# Remove hosts from Hyper-v virtual machine connection list

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, connection, windows-8.1

When using the Hyper-V Virtual machine connection program to connect to a VM on another host, you can type the name/IP of the host in the first drop down, and then the second dropdown populates with the VMs running on that host.

I have had and removed a couple of servers with the Hyper-V role, and these are still listed in the dropdown of hosts. I would like to remove them, so I only see a list of currently active hosts, just for neatness.

Not a major issue, as I can simply ignore the ones I know to be inactive/removed, but would like to see if anyone has faced this before and knows how to remove them from the list?

Comment: No idea, but I would give the registry a search for one of the names you want to remove.

Comment: Will give that a go now.

Comment: Have searched the entire registry, but unfortunately the only reference to those remote machines I can find is in terminal server list, which I assume is the list of terminal servers I have connected to using RDP. Not sue where else they could be stored :S